# Google Finance - Get Quotes search box - Column Alignment

Tags: javascript, html, css

How does Google manage to properly align the second column *(i.e. the ticker name)* in the "Get Quotes" search box suggestion drop-down in [google finance url](http://finance.google.com)

**Example:** If you enter `iii` - the second column is perfectly aligned.

It does not use a fixed width font - so just adding the correct numbers of spaces to the *ticker* will not work.

How do they do that?
­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­

Answer (score 1):

most likely just using margins. float the first column left then set the margin to the width of the first column.

Answer (score 0):

I just viewed source with a DOM inspector and it appears that they are `span`s for each cell with a margin set (as Darren said) to position the right column over.